# Is there a way to get the name of a Windows service from the process PID during SERVICE_START_PENDING?

Tags: c#

I am trying to dynamically get the name of a Windows service from it's process during startup (SERVICE_START_PENDING status) using the PID of the process, but every method I try doesn't seem to associate the service name and PID until the service moves to the SERVICE_RUNNING status.

So far I have tried querying Win32_Services with WMI, executing "tasklist /SVC", and calling EnumServicesStatusEx with P/Invoke. They all show that the PID of the service is 0, even though the service process has a real PID.

Comment: The process is owned by the operating system (PID = 0) until it is started.  A PID is not assigned until it is started.

Comment: Assuming the service is not hosted in a shared process, you could simply get the service executable path from the configuration (`PathName`, some parsing may be required) and cross-reference this with `Win32_Process` (`ExecutablePath`; this will however require admin permissions for most services, as they're not running under the current user's credentials).

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a shared service (and most inbox svcs are not these days.) You can tell from the command line. So to dump the command line from pid:

```
gwmi win32_process | select name,processId,commandLine | select-string <PID> | Format-list -Property Line | Out-String -Width 4096
```

This will dump the "Line" property. The service name will come after the -s. To do it dynamically you'd have to parse for the -s.

For example, for the PID 2136 in the above I got the following:

**Line : @{name=svchost.exe; processId=2136; commandLine=C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted -p -s lmhosts}**

The -s arg is usually one of the last args listed. In the above the service is "lmhosts".